# Añadir un elemento en la posición correspondiente para mantener el orden ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una funcion que se llama add(por peticion del ejercicio), que lo que recibe un arraylist con los elementos que sea y un numero, lo que tiene que hacer es añadir ese numero en la posicion correspondiente, ya que el arraylist está ordenado y devuelve la posicion en la que se ha añadido. En mi cabeza es como muy simple pero luego he probado diferentes cosas y o me da error o se queda en bucle infinito como en el ejemplo.

```
public static int add(ArrayList<Double> lista, double num)
{
    
    
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
    {
        if(num<lista.get(i))//Para añadirlo al inicio
        {
            lista.add(0, num);
        }else{
            if(num>lista.get(i) && num<lista.get(i+1))
            {
                lista.add(i, num);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    return i;
  
}
```

Y aqui dejo un trozo del main:

```
ArrayList<Double> lista = new ArrayList();
    
    lista.add(0.1);
    lista.add(0.4);
    lista.add(0.8);
    lista.add(0.2);
    
    Collections.sort(lista);
    
    System.out.println("Elemento añadido en la posicion: "+add(lista, 0.3));
    System.out.println("Elemento añadido en la posicion: "+add(lista, 0.5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el código con explicación en comentarios:

```
public static int add(ArrayList < Double > lista, double num) {
        int i;
        /*
        Estando la lista ordenada de forma ascendente
        si el numero es menor o igual que lista[i]
        entonces insertarlo antes del elemento lista[i]
        y retornar el valor actual de i
        */
        for (i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            if (num <= lista.get(i)) {
                lista.add(i, num);
                return i;
            }
        }
        /*
        Si el numero no fue menor o igual a ninguno de los elementos
        de la lista entonces insertarlo al final
        y retornar el nuevo tamaño de la lista
        */
        lista.add(num);
        return lista.size() - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias funcionó perfecto y lo entendí con los comentarios